# Can I control the order of _local_ repos in artifactory?

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, artifactory

Im using Artifactory for Nuget.

In my virtual repo I have two local repos and one public (cached) repo. Clients will be configured to use that virtual repo.

I might have packages that overlap between the two local repos- what happens then? When a client pulls nuget packages or does a nuget restore.

It looks like I can set the order of local repos in the virtual repo (at least in the UI I can move them below and above each other). If I have the same package in both local repos will artifactory only return the package from the local repo I have configured to be first in the list?

Answer (score 1):

The [Virtual Repository page](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Virtual+Repositories) is quite clear:

> The Included Repositories section displays the effective list of actual repositories included in this virtual repository.
>   If any of the available repositories you have selected are themselves virtual repositories, then the Included Repositories section will display the local and remote repositories included within them.
>   The Included Repository list is automatically updated in case any of the nested virtual repositories change.
>
> The search/resolution order when requesting artifacts from a virtual repository is always:
>
> - Local repositories
> - Remote repository caches
> - Remote repositories themselves.
>
> **The order within these categories is controlled by the order they are presented in the Selected Repositories list.**

Comment: ah missed that bit thanks. So can you confirm that it will ONLY return the duplicate package from the first local repo? It wont like pull from the first repo first and then overwrite any duplicate packages when it pulls from the second repo?

Comment: @red888 I haven't tested that particular scenario, but that would be my understanding, yes.